# why xunit not allow test a method with parameters?

Tags: xunit

I am learning to use unit test, i create a project, add xunit reference.
And following codes:

```
namespace UnitTestProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [Fact]
        private void test(int number1, string number2)
        {

            int result = number1 + Convert.ToInt32(number2);
            Assert.IsType(Type.GetType("Int32"), result);
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

When i run the test using xunit gui tool, it said:

> UnitTestProject.Form1.test : System.InvalidOperationException : Fact
>   method UnitTestProject.Form1.test cannot have parameters Stack Trace: 
>   於 Xunit.Sdk.FactCommand.Execute(Object testClass)
>   Xunit.Sdk.FixtureCommand.Execute(Object testClass)
>   Xunit.Sdk.BeforeAfterCommand.Execute(Object testClass)
>   Xunit.Sdk.LifetimeCommand.Execute(Object testClass)
>   Xunit.Sdk.ExceptionAndOutputCaptureCommand.Execute(Object testClass)

So, how can i test the method/function with parameters?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Also you can use `[Theory]` instead of `[Fact]`. It will allow you to create test methods with different parameters.
E.g.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1, "22")]
[InlineData(-1, "23")]
[InlineData(0, "-25")]
public void test(int number1, string number2)
{
    int result = number1 + Convert.ToInt32(number2);
    Assert.IsType(Type.GetType("Int32"), result);
}
```

p.s. With xUnit it would be better to make test methods public.

Comment: thanks, but can i set the InlineData in random value?Or better to say,InlineData accept inline method/variable?

Comment: You can why not. See a dirty example below.

Comment: @Shiba generally you shouldn't use random values in your tests. In your example method if one random number fails you will have no idea what the numbers were that caused the problem. Try to make your tests deterministic, and feed in a range of expected, unexpected and extreme inputs.

Answer (score 15):

About random values and inline methods/variables in tests.
This code generates 100 random int/string pairs for your test.

```
    [Theory]
    [PropertyData("GetTestData")]
    public void test(int number1, string number2)
    {

        int result = number1 + Convert.ToInt32(number2);
        var expectedType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        Assert.IsType(expectedType, result);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetTestData
    {
        get { return Enumerable.Repeat(0, 100).Select(x => GenerateTestData()); }
    }

    private static object[] GenerateTestData()
    {
        var rand = new Random(0);
        return new object[] {rand.Next(0,100), rand.Next(0,100).ToString()};
    }
```

Comment: But why? If it fails you can't reproduce it. Generate your set with random values once an fix them in your test.

Answer (score 2):

How would xunit know what to supply as values for the arguments? A unit test needs to be a self contained test which sets up an environment with data, performs the required action, and then asserts that the results are what are expected. Your test is not self contained because it relies on external values for `number1` and `number2`. Try the following:

```
[Fact]
private void TestAdd() {
    //arrange
    int number1 = 10;
    string number2 = "10";

    //act
    object result = Add(number1,number2);

    //assert
    Assert.IsType(Type.GetType("Int32"), result);
}

private object Add(int number1, string number2)
{
    return number1 + Convert.ToInt32(number2);
}
```

Something to note, what you are trying to do (parameterized unit testing) is possible with the [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) tool

Comment: Thanks you. But today many application is interact with end user. For example, my job mostly like work in account system, inventory system. I cannot assume the user's input data. I am new in it, still finding the value of unit test.

Comment: Your functions should accept certain data ranges. Typically you would test the ouliers of that range, the exceptional cases, and then something within the range (for sanity). But check out Pex, it will generate input data for you to test your functions

Comment: Thanks you, it seem Pex is what i want.